# Inserting values with a foreign key relationship into two different tables simultaneously? (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, lastinsertid, last-insert-id

So I have 2 tables:

- `users` with columns `id` (primary, auto_increment), `username`, `password`, `person_id` (foreign key)
- people with columns `id` (primary, auto_increment), `first_name`, `last_name`

What I'm trying to do is when registering a new account have a new row inserted into `people` and then have a new row inserted into `users` with the `people.id` as foreign key `users.person_id`.

Right now I have 2 php functions that get executed right after eachother, firstly one with this query:

> insert into people (first_name, last_name) values (:firstname,
>   :lastname)

Secondly one with this query:

> insert into users (username, password, person_id) values (:user,
>   :pass, LAST_INSERT_ID())

All of this works fine except for the fact that `last_insert_id()` keeps giving value `0` instead of the id from the previous query. Is it maybe not possible to use `last_insert_id()` when using 2 separate queries? If so what would be the best way to go about it then?

This is my relevant php code:

```
//make new person
$newPerson = new PeopleManagement();
$pm = $newPerson->createNewPerson($_POST["firstName"], $_POST["lastName"]);

//make new user
$newUsr = new Authentication();
$ac = $newUsr->registerNewUser($_POST["user"], $_POST["pass"]);


public function registerNewUser ($user, $pass) {
    try {

        $dbm = new PDO(DBCONFIG::$db_conn, DBCONFIG::$db_user, DBCONFIG::$db_pass);
        $dbm->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dbm->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);        

            hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $sql = "insert into users (username, password, person_id) values (:user, :pass, LAST_INSERT_ID())";

            $stmt = $dbm->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':user' => $user,
                ':pass' => $hash
            ));

            $dbm = null;

    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        return "Could not connect to database";
    }
}

public function createNewPerson($firstName, $lastName) {

    $dbm = new PDO($this->dbConn, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);

    $sql = "insert into people (first_name, last_name) values (:firstname, :lastname)";

    $stmt = $dbm->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':firstname' => $firstName,
        ':lastname' => $lastName
    ));

    $dbm = null;
}
```

Comment: Are the two queries using the same connection?

Comment: They both use PDO in the function to open their own connection for the query

Comment: Show the code so we can see what you are really doing and in what order

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() is connection based, so the two queries need to use the same connection for this to work.

Comment: You could also use the PHP/PDO `->last_insert_id()` to capture the id created by the first INSERT and use it in the second

Comment: @frequent_sleeper Opening a new connection for every query isn't a good idea - connections are a limited resource and can be easily exhausted if opened in a loop.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added my code

Comment: Ok so you are making a new connection in each method **BAD** make the connection once in the `__construct` method and keep `$dbm` in an instance property. Then your SQL method should work

Comment: O actually I see they are 2 different classes. So make another class for your connection, and pass that object to each of your Model's for them to use. This keeps only one connection that all models use and your SQL code should work

Comment: @RiggsFolly post as answer please

Comment: @e4c5 Too busy. Unless I recode the whole thing it is most likely to turn into a _Rabbit Hole_ answer with almost perpetual _Now this does not work issues_

Comment: @RiggsFolly good point

Comment: @RiggsFolly I made a class DBCONFIG with a function initDb that has `$dbm = new PDO($db_conn, $db_user, $db_pass); return $dbm` in it and I  call that in my other functions as such: `$db = new DBCONFIG(); $dbm = $db->initDb();` but it still gives me value 0

Comment: Better ask another question and put all the code in it for us to see